# Modeling a dataset where some the existence of some features are dependent on other features

Tags: modeling, feature-engineering

Given a dataset of series of events, structured roughly as follows:

```
series_id | number of events | average # days between events | average # days between most recent 5 events
 0          2                  5                                          
 1          1                  
 2          3                  8
 3          6                  6.7                             6
```

Some features only make sense when other features have certain values (like average # of days between most recent 5 events should only have a value when the number of events is >= 5) -- how should the data be modified so I can still model it with traditional techniques like logistic regression, where all the values have to be non-empty? Traditionally, I'm aware that NaN values would be filled with the median or some other generic statistic, but it doesn't seem to make sense here. Filling it with 0 seems problematic as well, since e.g. an average # of days between events actually being 0 has a specific meaning, whereas the lack of a value might almost be an important feature in itself.